# What is PHP_INI_PERDIR and PHP_INI_USER in .user.ini file?

Tags: php

I am beginner to php and learning about ini files. I have read about these two modes **PHP_INI_PERDIR** and **PHP_INI_USER** that are recognized in .user.ini file as i read in php.net at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php#115455) but don't understand what these two modes are and why and where these are used.

Can anyone tell ?

Comment: They just indicate where you're able to change them. Some configuration settings can be set at runtime with `ini_set`, others cannot. See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Comment: Please vote if you found the answer a good explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The setting PHP_INI_USER allows the developer to set INI settings programatically using ini_set() within PHP code. The setting PHP_INI_PERDIR only allows you to place setting in a configuration file php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf the later two are web server configuration files.

The reason why you might put a setting in .htaccess is so that system administrators can expose web server configuration and allow PHP configuration in the same file per web site. The httpd.conf allows for the opposite-- allowing only system administrators (or those who can manage a web server) to make settings in a more secure web server configuration file.

Comment: I understand but one thing that you didn't tell that where we put these two modes ? in php.ini file or in .user.ini file or in .htaccess file ?

Comment: I think the OP was specifically asking *where* it is determined in which mode PHP is running -- and how to change it.

Answer (score 3):

The Mode PHP_INI_USER allow entry to be set in user scripts (like with ini_set()) or in [Windows Registry](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#configuration.changes.windows)

The Mode PHP_INI_PERDIR allow to entry to set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini(since PHP 5.3).

We can read detail where a configuration setting may be set in [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)

Hope this will help everyone and make it clear enough between the MODES.